# What is the history of the default precision for printf floats?

Tags: c, standards

It seems that everyone uses a default precision of 6 characters when formatting a float using printf.

Why 6?

Did this come about before 32bit floats were widely used?

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that 32-bit floats can beat this. They can't. This number comes from 32-bit floats.

Comment: How do you figure that? 33.30 as a 32bit IEE754 float is 33.29999923706055 exactly.

Comment: An IEEE754 (not "IEE754") binary32 has 7.22 decimal digits. You appear to be talking about binary64s (i.e. doubles), or perhaps something else entirely. Do some reading on the IEEE754 floating point formats.

Comment: No you seem to be confusing what I mean. The exact literal decimal presresentation is not 7.22 digits, it can be a huge number of digits, and for whatever reason 6 was chosen as the cut-off point.

Comment: No, it can be 7.22 digits (the exact amount depends on the value). It cannot be more. There is insufficient space in the format for more precision than that. Just because you print more than 6 sigfigs doesn't mean any of them has meaning; that's a bug in your output routine (or you accidentally converted to `double`). 6 is not arbitrary. It wasn't "chosen" either, but it's a consequence of the size and layout of the IEEE754 format. Like I said (over three years ago!), read up on how floating point works.

Comment: You are obviously not getting it... the purpose of printf is to print the value actually stored in decimal. To do that you need a lot more than 7.22 digits. It has nothing to do with the precision of the float.

Comment: A float _doesn't store_ "a lot more than 7.22 digits", but okay you know best :)

Comment: You still don't get it... A real number has an actual real value that in base 10 takes whatever many digits it takes to show it. A float has a decimal precision because it is a sum of fractions and so has a quanta of real numbers that it can jump between for its various values.

Answer (score 6):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point), the common IEEE 754 representation of floating point with 32 bits has a precision of about 7 decimal digits. So 6 looks like a reasonable value.

You need double precision (64 bits) to get about 16 decimal digits.

Answer (score 3):

Well, no, this did not come about before 32 bit floats were widely used.   The first floating point representations - which came to be well before IEEE specifications existed -  were 32 bits (or thereabouts), so there was no "default precision" for outputting floating point values before that.

Anyway, for a 32 bit floating point type, a typical size of the significand or mantissa was 20 to 25 bits (IEEE 32 bit floats have a significand of 24 bits), which works out between four and seven significant decimal figures representing maximum precision.   (`24*log(2)` is roughly equal to `7.2`).

A typical 64 bit floating point representation has a significand of between 50 and 55 bits (64 bit IEEE representations have a 53 bit significand) which works out to about fifteen decimal places representing maximum precision.

That means programmers would often default to outputting floating point values at between 5 and 6 decimal places.   Less precision would truncate values (increase error incurred by printing out a value and reading it in again) and more precision would tend to output "noise"  (stray digits further after the decimal point, which affected human readability, and did not do much to help the write/read round trip).

All of this predated C though - in fact it predated Algol (one of the early programming languages, who's design influenced languages that were the ancestors of C).

Comment: I don't agree about you calculation of precision. In a standard 23bit mantessa the least significant fraction is 1/8388608, so the number of significant digits is at least 14.

Answer (score 2):

In the history of `printf`, the 6 digit default goes back at least as far as Version 5 Unix. See ancient source code:

- [fltpr.s](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V5/usr/source/s4/fltpr.s) the `pfloat` function, which implements `%f`, and the `pscien` function, which implements `%e`, both contain the magic number 6 in the instruction `mov $6,_ndigit`
- [printf.s](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V5/usr/source/s4/printf.s) which calls `pfloat` and `pscien` when it finds a `%f` or `%e` conversion. An important variable is `ndfnd` which will be 0 if the conversion didn't specify a number of digits.
- [ecvt.s](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V5/usr/source/s3/ecvt.s) the `fcvt` and `ecvt` functions which actually produce the digit strings